# A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_local_notifications'

Tags: flutter

I installed the flutter local notification plugin in my project but when I run flutter run it gives me the following error

*What went wrong:
There was a problem configuring the ':flutter_local_notifications' project.

Failed to notify listener of project review.
Unable to get unknown property 'android' for project ':flutter_local_notifications' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
Unable to get unknown property 'android' for project ':flutter_local_notifications' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

To try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get stack trace.
Run with the --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.

I've tried everything and nothing solves my problem.

I've already tried updating the local warning version, I've already reinstalled flutter and dart, I've tried all the settings I found in build.gradle, I've tried everything, I'm even considering formatting the machine to see if it solves it.